# OPENCV - write code to detect specific regex text in a printed image using opencv, and get their x,y coordinate in image

Tags: python, opencv

I am very new to this, just trying to learn something new. I want that I can search a specif regex text in an image, and create rectangle over it using opencv.

Please see the image. [image]

I try to use chatgpt to get this code, but this does not create red outline over the `123` text.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import re

# Load the image using OpenCV
image_path = 'ocr.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Define the regex pattern to search for specific text
regex_pattern = r'123'

# Convert the image to grayscale for text detection
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Use pytesseract to perform OCR and extract text
extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)

# Find all matches of the regex pattern in the extracted text
matches = re.finditer(regex_pattern, extracted_text, re.IGNORECASE)

print(matches)
# Initialize a list to store the coordinates of matching text
matching_coordinates = []

print('matching ', matching_coordinates)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
    match_text = match.group()
    start = match.start()
    end = match.end()
    print('-------------', match_text, start, end)
    # Search for the coordinates of the matched text
    for box in pytesseract.image_to_boxes(image).splitlines():
        print(box)
        box = box.split()
        box.pop(0)
        print(box)
        if start <= int(box[0]) < end:
            x, y = int(box[1]), int(box[2])
            matching_coordinates.append((x, y))

# Draw bounding boxes around the detected text and display the image
for x, y in matching_coordinates:
    print('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', x)
    cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)  # Draw a red dot at the coordinates

cv2.imshow("Image with Text Detection", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Print the matching coordinates
for x, y in matching_coordinates:
    print(f"Matching Text Found at X: {x}, Y: {y}")
```

This code is not displaying a red marker outside `123` text. Please help.